# How to integrate Polymer With Mgwt

Tags: cordova, gwt, polymer, mgwt

I want to use Polymer Feature in my mgwt + apache cordova application. Its working fine in web browser but after I install on android device its not working.

NOTE:I also copied Polymer component in www folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution actually their was problem with my content layout & my scrollview is not getting height.

Comment: Please share a sample demo. It would be nice to explore this combination.

Comment: @SSR i'll definite share once i complete.

Comment: till then look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27287348/how-to-register-custom-html-element-as-widget-in-gwt