# How to register Custom HTML Element as widget in GWT

Tags: java, android, gwt, polymer, mgwt

Hi folks Did someone have any idea how to register custom html element as GWT widget uiBinder and use them directly in place of using in HTMLPanel.

For e.g. if I'm using [Google Polymer](https://www.polymer-project.org) in my [mgwt](http://www.m-gwt.com/) project I'm using custom html element as

```
                 <g:HTMLPanel >
                    <paper-shadow class="{style.card}">
                        <mgwt:touch.TouchPanel ui:field="touchPanel">
                            <mgwt:panel.flex.FlexPanel orientation="VERTICAL" alignment="CENTER">
                                <g:Image url="{global.getDirection.getSafeUri.asString}" />
                                <g:HTMLPanel>Take me to Deal</g:HTMLPanel>
                            </mgwt:panel.flex.FlexPanel>
                        </mgwt:touch.TouchPanel>
                    </paper-shadow>
                </g:HTMLPanel>
```

I want to register/create paper-shadow as custom widget so that I can write code as so that its easy to handel events

```
                <polymer:paper-shadow class="{style.card}">
                    <mgwt:touch.TouchPanel ui:field="touchPanel">
                        <mgwt:panel.flex.FlexPanel orientation="VERTICAL" alignment="CENTER">
                            <g:Image url="{global.getDirection.getSafeUri.asString}" />
                            <g:HTMLPanel>Take me to Deal</g:HTMLPanel>
                        </mgwt:panel.flex.FlexPanel>
                    </mgwt:touch.TouchPanel>
                <polymer:paper-shadow>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't easily add a new custom element that UiBinder will understand. You can add one to [your custom widget](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26423827/181497), though.

You'll notice that GWT allows custom attributes on these custom elements, like in [`DockLayoutPanel`](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/DockLayoutPanel.html):

```xml
<g:DockLayoutPanel unit='EM'>
  <g:north size='5'>
    <g:Label>Top</g:Label>
  </g:north>
  <g:center>
    <g:Label>Body</g:Label>
  </g:center>
  <g:west size='192'>
    <g:HTML>
      <ul>
        <li>Sidebar</li>
        <li>Sidebar</li>
        <li>Sidebar</li>
      </ul>
    </g:HTML>
  </g:west>
</g:DockLayoutPanel>
```

Notice the `<g:north size='5'>` element - if you look into `DockLayoutPanel`'s source code, you'll see that it is handled by this method:

```java
public void addNorth(Widget widget, double size) {
    insert(widget, Direction.NORTH, size, null);
}
```

No `@UiChild` annotation and an extra parameter means something "magical" is happening behind scenes. And true enough, there's a `DockLayoutPanelParser` class that handles this special case. You'll notice that it implements the `ElementParser` - unfortunately, [it's not possible to "plug in" your own `ElementParser`](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=4461).

There was a project, [gwt-customuibinder](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-customuibinder/), that tried sidestepping this limitation, but it's been deprecated for newer (2.5+?) versions of GWT:

> Please note that with the newer releases of GWT, this project is now deprecated as many of the techniques used to add custom element parsers to UiBinder are now not possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using and maintaining [this fork](https://github.com/comunes/gwt-polymer) of this [gwt-polymer wrap](https://github.com/rodrigopecci/gwt-polymer).

In the test app you can see several samples of use of polymer widgets in gwt, how to wrap existing html polymer elements, how to create new ones, the use with uibinder, etc.

Comment: thanks folks but when this question was asked this lib was not available